# How to call member functions traversing up the class hierarchy

Tags: c++

Suppose classes have properties/traits and I needed to accumulate those in derived classes, how would that work in C++?

```
struct Base
{
    virtual Array names() { return { "A", "B" }; }
};

struct Derived : Base
{
   Array names() override { return { "C", "D", "E" }; }
};

struct FurtherDerived : Derived
{
   Array names() override { return { "F", "G" }; }
};
```

Now if I wanted to implement a recursive function allNames() in Base that derives all names concatenated, how would that work? For example

```
FurtherDerived fd;
fd.allNames() ==> {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"}

Derived d;
d.allNames() ==> {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}

Base b;
b.allNames() ==> {"A", "B"}
```

I can't for the life of me figure this out.

Comment: `Derived::names()` should return `Base::names() + { "C", "D", "E" }`, `FurtherDerived::names()` - `Derived::names() + { "F", "G" }` and so on.

Comment: Yes, however this needs to be implemented in Base only.

Comment: I don't think virtual function are made for this or is the right solution. I'd suggest either not using inheritance hierarchy and use something more akind of a tuple or composition, or accumulate the result manually as SombreroChicken suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call each base class method before adding your own:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual Array names() { return { "A", "B" }; }
};

struct Derived : Base
{
   Array names() override { return Base::names() + { "C", "D", "E" }; }
};

struct FurtherDerived : Derived
{
   Array names() override { return Derived::names() + { "F", "G" }; }
};
```

This of course assumes that your `Array` type supports merging with `operator+`.

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP wants.  They want to call a function call `allNames` that will recurse down the hierarchy and get all the names for them.

Comment: @NathanOliver Well I want a trampoline but we can't always get what we want

Comment: Basically I want a function that returns the inherited names for any instance of any of these classes. So far this was not possible w/o duplicating code in each class that explicitly calls SuperClass::names(). So yes, this answer works. But I would like to be able to 'declare' names per class w/o the reference to super class.

Comment: Flagged this as the working answer to the question. Although, since the actual task is rather comprehensive, I now went with metaclasses that support class-side virtual methods and reflection.

Answer (score 0):

> Now if I wanted to implement a recursive function allNames() in Base that derives all names concatenated, how would that work?

You won't be able to do this in C++.  There is no reflection (yet) so you can't know what the hierarchy is without specifying it yourself.  What you can do though is specify it yourself in the    `allNames` function and leverage the fact that you can call the base class functions from the derived class.  Doing that would give you something like:

```
using Array = std::vector<std::string>;

Array operator +(Array lhs, Array const& rhs)
{
    lhs.insert(lhs.end(), rhs.begin(), rhs.end());
    return lhs;
}

struct Base
{
    virtual Array names() { return { "A", "B" }; }
    Array allNames() { return names(); }
};

struct Derived : Base
{
   Array names() override { return { "C", "D", "E" }; }
   Array allNames() { return Base::names() + names(); }
};

struct FurtherDerived : Derived
{
   Array names() override { return { "F", "G" }; }
   Array allNames() { return Base::names() + Derived::names() + names(); }
};

int main()
{
    FurtherDerived f;
    auto ret = f.allNames();
    for (auto const& e : ret)
        std::cout << e << " ";
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to call `return Derived::allNames() + names();` from `FurtherDerived::allNames()` instead? The same for other classes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Repeating the entire hierarchy in code isn't viable, however. The goal is to allow developers to add their own subclasses by declaring these properties for their classes. They don't know the full hierarchy.